# How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?

Tags: desktop-background, appearance

How do  I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow with my own set of images?

- With the images coming from a pictures folder, or pre-selected
- With the images displayed in order, or randomly
- With the images changing every few minutes, or after random periods of time

Comment: In 2018, Variety seems to me the best tool for this job: https://peterlevi.com/variety/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### For 11.04 and previous versions

There's a program for creating wallpaper slideshows called CREBS. Check out this article about it: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/crebs-the-ultimate-wallpaper-slideshow-application

A simpler app that has fewer features but is easier to use can be found here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Wallpaper+Slideshow?content=125178

[image]

Answer (score 297):

If you use it to manage your photos and like it easy I recommend to use `Shotwell`, which should be installed by default.

Open it:

[image: open shotwell]

Select the photos you want to be set as background slideshow:

[image: select images]

Open `File` → `Set as Desktop Slideshow` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>:

[image: set as slideshow]

Adjust time settings:

[image: set time]

Done.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I like this solution over Wallch.. as you don't have to install any extra apps to achieve the same purpose

Comment: do i need to create a startup application for the same or will it work everytime?

Comment: Old thread, but comes up highest in search.
This is BY FAR the easiest method. Still works perfectly and, to @Arun Kumar's question, loads automatically with no further work.
Note: When trying to import images from a symlink, I had to change the import location in Settings by picking the folder, otherwise it would not allow selection of the images.

Comment: Is the solution displaying Images randomly or sequentially? The images are zoomed or filled or spanned or something? Do they fit the desktop perfectly?

Comment: is there a way to set the photos to be centred, scaled, zoomed, stretched etc with this feature? I dont see anything in preferences.

Comment: Once I have set the desktop background slideshow from Shotwell, how do I disable it?

Comment: Creating wallpaper slideshows  is a feature that was added in Shotwell 0.8.0, released 2010-12-23.

Comment: @Kalamalka Kid If you want your images scaled to your screen with e.g. a black background, follow the above post then go to Ubuntu System Settings > Appearance > Look > Background. Choose 'Scale' in the dropdown box and black as the color. This works in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: The problem I see with `Shotwell` is that it has a limited number of images to use (roughly 2000), and before processing them, shotwell copies the images (for better performance, I assume), duplicating thus their sizes on the disk.

Comment: one single issue, you need to select the photos themselves by multi select, selecting a folder or an album in the tree does not help, besides that GREAT UP!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: On 18.04 it just gives me a colored (no image) background despite selecting about 20 images to rotate.

Comment: They seem to have taken it out because Shotwell 0.28.4 does not have the feature you are talking about.

Comment: This solution works on 18.04 in Jul/2021. Nice answer, thank you Jakob

Comment: Shotwell works best ( in my opinion ) without having to create your own xml files for a slide show. If you want them spanned for dual screen you can use gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options spanned

Answer (score 88):

### Wallch

In software center there are two wallpaper changer - *wallch* for Gnome-Shell/Unity/Gnome-Classic and *Wally* for KUbuntu.

Lets concentrate on *Wallch*.

*Sadly* the version of Wallch in the software centre is outdated and has many issues especially with 14.04! There's a repository with the recent version.

To install, add the repository (you don't need to do this on 16.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily
```

Then install Wallch:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Then start from Dash:

[image]

Lets now launch the application preferences:

[image]

Let's untick the bubble notification - its annoying - at the same time you could disable sounds!

[image]

At the same time you can define the start-up options:

[image]

Save - and add a folder of pictures - in this example, use `/usr/share/backgrounds` for the default wallpapers that come with Ubuntu

[image]

Now we've got two choices:

**Start up choice 1**

(thanks @Naruto)

keep *wallch* in in the launcher

[image]

exit wallch and start changing wallpapers

[image]

**Start up choice 2**

start *wallch* on login without needing to have a launcher

From the dash:

[image]

Then create a new startup application with the command `wallch --constant`

[image]

N.B. - for some computers this will not work.  The solution is to introduce a delay to the startup of the wallch daemon as per the following Q&A:

[Wallch not auto-cycling backgrounds on log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117721/wallch-not-auto-cycling-backgrounds-on-log-in)

Comment: Wallch is defective on Lubuntu 14.04. The change interval keeps defaulting to 10 minutes or thereabouts after a reboot.

Comment: fire a bug report on launchpad - the maintainer is an active user here as well and will hopefully respond quickly to any issues reported.

Comment: The version on the software centre is just outdated! Here's where to install the recent version:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch`

The software centre version didn't work for me but the up to date one works flawlessly! I'm 14.04 64 bits

Comment: A daily build looks risky. Is there not another ppa for wallch?

Comment: @fossfreedom♦ does this works on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 54):

## <sub><sub><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></sub></sub>    Variety

**Homepage:** http://peterlevi.com/variety
**Github:** https://github.com/varietywalls/variety

> Variety is a wallpaper manager for Linux systems. It supports numerous
>   desktops and wallpaper sources, including local files and online
>   services: Flickr, Wallhaven, Unsplash, and more.
>
> Where supported, Variety sits as a tray icon to allow easy pausing and
>   resuming. Otherwise, its desktop entry menu provides a similar set of
>   options.
>
> Variety also includes a range of image effects, such as oil painting
>   and blur, as well as options to layer quotes and a clock onto the
>   background.

[image]

### Install

It's available in the Universe repo. To install it, run

```
sudo apt install variety
```

---

Also you can install it from [Peter Levi's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

Comment: Wow, amazing software. Very nice features, including nice display of clock and proverbs.

Comment: Thanks for that, much better than wallch, it let's you download  images from multiple sources.

Comment: I tested them all and this was the best, more possibilities and features

Answer (score 29):

Create an XML file yourself. Use this script as a starting point with caution, it may have some errors.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="background.xml"
DURATION=10.0
TRANSITION=0.0

CURRENTDIR=$PWD
TRANSITION_XML="
<static>
    <duration>$DURATION</duration>
    <file>$CURRENTDIR/%s</file>
</static>
<transition>
    <duration>$TRANSITION</duration>
    <from>$CURRENTDIR/%s</from>
    <to>$CURRENTDIR/%s</to>
</transition>
"

# Random order
shopt -s nullgob nocaseglob        # ignore non-existant extensions, case-insensitve
IMGS=( *.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif} )
INDICES=( $(shuf -e ${!IMGS[@]}) ) # randomize indices of images
INDICES+=(${INDICES[0]})           # go back to first image after last
COUNTER=${#IMGS[@]}

exec > "$FILE"                     # all further output to the XML file
echo "<background><starttime></starttime>"

for ((i = 0; i < COUNTER; i++))
do
    index=${INDICES[i]}
    printf "$TRANSITION_XML" "${IMGS[index]}" "${IMGS[index]}" "${IMGS[index + 1]}"
done

echo "</background>"
```

Instructions:

Once the `background.xml` file has been generated, right-click on the desktop, select *Change Background Image*, click *Add*..., then navigate to the directory containing the XML file. Just above the "Open" button change the selector from "Image" to "All files", then select the background.xml file and click on the "Open" button. The file can be renamed to be more descriptive, such as `my_family.xml`, `landscapes-3.xml`, etc., allowing one to have multiple slide show playlists.

Comment: I have modified the above script, adapting it to be a Nautilus Script: http://www.stefanobagnatica.it/dl/jaub/create_slideshow.sh.txt
Just put that in .local/share/nautilus/scripts, than in Nautilus select folder with wallpapers and right click > Scripts > create_slideshow: it will create XML file in .backgrounds and XML wallpaper definition file in gnome-background-properties folder.

Comment: @Pisu could you please upload that script to another location? It now gives a 404 error.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8091445/

Comment: while this might seem like a nice answer, there are no instructions as to what to do with the file after it is created.

Comment: The DURATION and TRANSITION values in the script are suitable for testing, but for actual use should be changed to something like 1795.0 and 5.0, giving static display times of half an hour per image with 5-second dissolve transitions.

Comment: @Kalamalka Kid, once the background.xml file has been generated, right-click on the desktop, select Change Background Image, click Add..., then navigate to the directory containing the XML file.  Just above the "Open" button change the selector from "Image" to "All files", then select the background.xml file and click on the "Open" button.  The file can be renamed to be more descriptive, such as "my_family.xml", "landscapes-3.xml", etc., allowing one to have multiple slide show playlists.

Comment: A cleaned-up and commented version of the script can be obtained from http://paste.ubuntu.com/23533511/ that outputs neatly formatted and indented XML code with comments.  It has been tested on Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid Lynx" with GNOME 2.30 as a Nautilus script and as a stand-alone script run from a terminal window in the directory containing the wallpaper images to be used in a slide show.

Comment: Just tried it out out Ubuntu 16.04 - unfortunately there is no "All files" selector anymore. Any idea how do make it work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 9):

For gnome 3, generate the xml using one of the previous answers, then you could add the generated xml via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/pykler/.backgrounds/realtime/background.xml'
```

Another Solution (this will add your bg to the Appearance area under gnome-control-center):

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/

cat >~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/custom-wallpapers.xml <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">
<wallpapers>
  <wallpaper deleted="false">
    <name>Pykler</name>
    <filename>/home/pykler/.backgrounds/realtime/background.xml</filename>
    <options>zoom</options>
  </wallpaper>
 </wallpapers>
EOF
```

Replace the name "Pykler" and the path "/home/pykler/.backgrounds/realtime/background.xml" as needed.

Answer (score 6):

For Gnome 3, you can use the Wallpaper Slideshow App.

[image: Wallpaper Slideshow App screenshot]

According to its developer, it has the following features:

- Lets you choose the folder via a browser.
- Lets you set the timeout in seconds.
- Lets you chose depth of subdirectory.
- You can enable or disable it with a single click.
- Full-feature tooltips

To download:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/gnome-3-wp/gnome-3-wp.git
```

Then run `wp-show` in the gnome-3-wp folder in your home folder.

For more information, see [here](http://dsathe.blogspot.com/2011/06/auto-background-changer-for-gnome-3-gui.html) and [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/wallpaper-slideshow-app-for-gnome-3/).

Comment: Won't work on newlly installed Oneiric Ubuntu 11.10. Had to fix the #!/usr/bin/env python2 to #!/usr/bin/env python but still it gives a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 4):

Use cortina, it works pretty well.

It can set the desktop background picture to be set a random file from a given directory.

It can be installed via Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: I don't see this in the Software Centre in Natty, am I missing something, or has it been removed?

Comment: Cortina is only available in the (currently unreleased) Ubuntu 12.04. However, [it is broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cortina/+bug/948914).

Answer (score 4):

Ok here is how I did it, which is probably not the best way to do it but it worked and I didn't have to install anything to do it.  Back in 11.10 I found the below python script (`slideshow.py`) which generates a `slideshow.xml` file (run from directory with the images in it).  This is still the file needed in 12.04 but you also need another XML file.  Put the XML file generated by `slideshow.py` script in `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest` and `chown` it to `root`.  Once that is done you'll need to run the second python script (`wallpapers.py`) which was adapted from the first.  Put the file generated from `wallpapers.py` in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties` and again `chown` it to root.  At that point you should be able to go into "System Settings" -> Appearance and pick your slideshow or any of the pics in it.

slideshow.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
# slideshow.py
import glob, os
import shutil
import time
import Image

filelist=[]
def filelie(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
       wenjian=os.path.splitext(path)[1][1:]
       if wenjian=="jpg" or wenjian=="png" or wenjian=="gif":
        try:
          kuan,gao = Image.open(path).size
          if kuan>=1024 and gao>=768:
            filelist.append(path)
        except IOError:
         pass
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            itemsrc = os.path.join(path, item)
            filelie(itemsrc)

curdir = os.getcwd()
filelie(curdir)
currentImageFiles = filelist
#print filelist
if os.path.isfile('slideshow.xml'):
 os.remove('slideshow.xml')


currentTime = time.localtime()
length = len(currentImageFiles)

f = file('slideshow.xml', 'w')

f.write('<background>\n')
f.write('\t<starttime>\n')
f.write('\t\t<year>' + str(currentTime.tm_year) + '</year>\n')
f.write('\t\t<month>' + str(currentTime.tm_mon) + '</month>\n')
f.write('\t\t<day>' + str(currentTime.tm_mday) + '</day>\n')
f.write('\t\t<hour>' + str(currentTime.tm_hour) + '</hour>\n')
f.write('\t\t<minute>' + str(currentTime.tm_min) + '</minute>\n')
f.write('\t\t<second>' + str(currentTime.tm_sec) + '</second>\n')
f.write('\t</starttime>\n')
f.write('<!--This animation will start at the time it created-->\n')

for i in currentImageFiles:
 length = length - 1
 f.write('\t<static>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<duration>96.0</duration>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<file>' + currentImageFiles[length] +'</file>\n')
 f.write('\t</static>\n')
 f.write('\t<transition>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<duration>3.0</duration>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<from>' + currentImageFiles[length] + '</from>\n')
 if length >= 1:
  f.write('\t\t<to>' + currentImageFiles[length-1] + '</to>\n')
 if length <1:
  f.write('\t\t<to>' + currentImageFiles[len(currentImageFiles)-1] + '</to>\n')
 f.write('\t</transition>\n')

f.write('</background>\n')
f.close()
```

wallpapers.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
import glob, os
import shutil
import time
import Image

filelist=[]
def filelie(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
       wenjian=os.path.splitext(path)[1][1:]
       if wenjian=="jpg" or wenjian=="png" or wenjian=="gif":
        try:
          kuan,gao = Image.open(path).size
          if kuan>=1024 and gao>=768:
            filelist.append(path)
        except IOError:
         pass
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            itemsrc = os.path.join(path, item)
            filelie(itemsrc)

curdir = os.getcwd()
filelie(curdir)
currentImageFiles = filelist
#print filelist
if os.path.isfile('mywallpapers.xml'):
 os.remove('mywallpapers.xml')


currentTime = time.localtime()
length = len(currentImageFiles)

f = file('mywallpapers.xml', 'w')

f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
f.write('<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">\n')
f.write('<wallpapers>\n')
f.write('\t<wallpaper deleted="false">\n')
f.write('\t\t<name>My custom Wallpapers</name>\n')
f.write('\t\t<filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/slideshow.xml</filename>\n')
f.write('\t\t<options>zoom</options>\n')
f.write('\t</wallpaper>\n')

for i in currentImageFiles:
 length = length - 1
 f.write('\t<wallpaper>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<name>' + os.path.basename(currentImageFiles[length]) +'</name>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<filename>' + currentImageFiles[length] +'</filename>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<options>zoom</options>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<pcolor>#000000</pcolor>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<scolor>#000000</scolor>\n')
 f.write('\t\t<shade_type>solid</shade_type>\n')
 f.write('\t</wallpaper>\n')

f.write('</wallpapers>\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in a program that automatically creates such a wallpaper-slideshow.

According to [this OMG! Ubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/wallpaper-gallery-is-a-shotwell-friendly-wallpaper-changer-for-ubuntu/), you have for example ['Wallpaper Gallery'](http://www.olmec.co.nz/software/wallpaperchanger/). It takes as input data tagged photos from your Shotwell gallery. Therefore it becomes very easy to add & remove photos for instance.

First select the tags concerning the photos you want to be displayed, then configure as you wish the switching time, the order, etc. Here some screenshots :

[image: Wallpaper Gallery display options]
[image: Wallpaper Gallery data source]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

Locate an already made animated wallpaper and modify it.

For example, there should be one in `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest` (at least on Precise Pangolin).

The file is called `precise.xml` in my case and it is an XML file. All you need to know to modify it is that any **tag** like `<background>` contains other tags and texts and must be closed with `</background>`.

Try to find out what these tags mean (see below), change the name of these pictures and **save as...** somewhere. Call it **whatever_you_want.xml**.

Then change your background: choose a new wallpaper by browsing your computer and, instead of choosing a *.jpg*, choose your *.xml*.

Some tags:

`<background>` contains everything. Your file must begin with it and end with `</background>`. It's called the root tag.
`<starttime>` defines when the diaporama starts. A precise date must be given, any date.
`<static>` contains the definition of a still image.
`<transition>` is used to fade from one image to the other.
`<duration>` gives in seconds the time during witch the picture is displayed or the fading time.
`<file>` contains a single image to show as still.
`<from>` and `<to>` contain single images which are respectively the one at the beginning and at the end of a fading.

Some additional hints:

By adding the number of seconds of all the `<duration>` tags in the file, you'll know how much time it takes to perform a complete loop of the diaporama.

The nicest configuration is this one (simplified, without durations):

```xml
<static>
    <file>image1</file>
</static>
<transition>
    <from>image1</from>
    <to>image2</to>
</transition>
<static>
    <file>image2</file>
</static>
<transition>
    <from>image2</from>
    <to>image3</to>
</transition>
...
```

Don't forget to end your diaporama with a transition to your first picture, or else it will abruptly change from one static to another.

I tried to do an animated background, once. Images displayed less than 1 second each. You can try it for fun, but frankly, you'll want to throw your mouse to the monitor before the end of the day.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted the changing wallpaper and custom wallpaper pictures to appear under the default options for selecting a wallpaper in Ubuntu 12.04,so I did the following

Using Terminal navigate to:

```
/usr/share/gnome-background-properties
```

typing `ls` will list all files in that folder you should see a file called precise-wallpapers.xml, back it up in case something goes wrong

```
sudo cp ./precise-wallpapers.xml ~
```

then edit it to add wallpapers that you want to appear in your default wallpaper options

```
sudo gedit precise-wallpapers.xml
```

this is how I added a polarbears wallpaper, previously I copied the precise.xml located in the contest folder and edited it with pictures that I wanted to display:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">
<wallpapers>
  <wallpaper deleted="false">
    <name>Ubuntu 12.04 Community Wallpapers</name>
    <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/precise.xml</filename>
    <options>zoom</options>
  </wallpaper>
  <wallpaper>
    <name>polarbears</name>
    <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/polarbears/polarbears.xml</filename>
    <options>zoom</options>
  </wallpaper>
  <wallpaper>
    <name>Delicate Petals</name>
    <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/Delicate_Petals_by_lefthandgergo.jpg</filename>
    <options>zoom</options>
    <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
    <scolor>#000000</scolor>
    <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
  </wallpaper>
  <wallpaper>
```

you can add regular jpg or png files, I recommend copying them to the /usr/share/backgrounds then adding them to this xml file. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Change it from appearance, under system settings as seen below

[image]

Or you can do so, by installing Desktop Nova.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install desktopnova desktopnova-tray desktopnova-module-gnome
```

Once installed, search for it in Dash, and click on it, and when the program open, add your images, and setup the time interval.

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>Command complements of [Desktopnova](http://www.howtoforge.com/desktopnova-automatically-change-wallpapers-on-ubuntu-11.04-with-classic-gnome)</sup>

Comment: quite detailed explanation @Mitch

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing a while back; here is my script: http://pastebin.com/FkaxaN3J

Just stick it in the directory, make executable, and run.

Comment: Your script looks pretty good. Are you up for creating a slightly different version to answer this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/35971/458 ? It has been open for 10 months and is not getting answers.

Comment: @RichardHolloway, that's a good question you've linked, but one that I've run out of time to help answer. If you or anyone else wants to take the script and run with it, they're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 2):

### <sub><sub><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></sub></sub>    Desk Changer for GNOME shell

**by egach**

In case you use gnome-shell (version > 3.8, default in Ubuntu 17.10 and later), use this nice extension.

> Simple wallpaper changer with multiple profile support. Supports
>   integration into the system menu or its own panel icon. The daemon is
>   written in Python and runs independently of the extension.

**Extension Homepage**: https://github.com/BigE/desk-changer/

[image]

### Install

First you have to install gnome-tweaks

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Visit the [gnome-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1131/desk-changer/) homepage and switch the slide on. Afterwards you can configure the extension to change the background's change time and the backgrounds itselfs. To do so open **gnome-tweaks**, go to the **Extension** tab and click on the **Configure** icon of the desk-changer.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this request, I was curious about a solution and found something to be able to get your wallpaper image to be a part of the default wallpaper selection when going into `System Settings >> Appearances`. Follow the steps below in a terminal:

1. `cd /usr/share/gnome-background-properties`

   - This will take you to the specific path mentioned
2. `sudo cp ./ubuntu-wallpapers.xml ~`

   - This will copy the file ubuntu-wallpapers.xml into your home
     directory
3. `sudo vim ./ubuntu-wallpapers.xml`

   - The command `vim` is a terminal editor but you can change it to `gedit` if you wish

Once you are in that file, you will see tags called `<wallpaper>` and `</wallpaper>` that is around the other tags like `<name>` and `<options>`. You will need to copy that and paste it right below that entry. Once done, you should edit that extra entry you added to match what you want. An example can be found below:

[image]

In this example, I made changes to the `<name>`, `<filename>`, `<pcolor>`, and `<scolor>` information to match what I needed for the wallpaper I wanted. Now I see the wallpaper as a default selection in the wallpaper section of the `System Settings -> Appearance` GUI:

[image]

If anything doesn't work, use the following command to import back the save file we made from above:

`sudo cp ~/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

### <sub><sub><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></sub></sub>    Random Wallpaper for GNOME shell

**by iFlow**

> In case you use gnome-shell (version > 3.12, default in Ubuntu 17.10
>   and later), use this nice extension.  This extension fetches a random
>   wallpaper from an online source and sets it as desktop background. 
>   The desktop background can be updated periodically or manually.
>
> Online sources:
>   - unsplash.com
>   - desktopper.co
>   - wallheaven.cc
>   - reddit.com
>   - basic JSON APIs or Files (See the GitHub wiki for more information) (Chromecast, Bing, NASA, Google Earth View, etc.)

**Extension Homepage**: https://github.com/ifl0w/RandomWallpaperGnome3

[image]

### Install

First you have to install gnome-tweaks

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Visit the [gnome-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1040/random-wallpaper/) homepage and switch the slide on. Afterwards you can configure the extension. To do so open **gnome-tweaks**, go to the **Extension** tab and click on the **Configure** icon of the random-wallpaper.

Answer (score -1):

[feh, an imlib2 based image viewer](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) is a very flexible, efficient and and powerful X11 image viewer aimed mostly at console users. "Unlike most other viewers, it does not have a fancy GUI, but simply displays images. It is controlled via commandline arguments and configurable key/mouse actions."

I'm doing randomized slideshows of a set of many thousands of images with it, in a deep directory structure.  When running in window mode, rather than desktop background, I can add comments to them easily when I see one I like, and go into sequential mode to look for similar ones.

Answer (score -3):

try slidewall as well, it has clock displayed..

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to help the OP understand how Slidewall can answer their question as well as how to get it  :-)

Answer (score -3):

Go to **System Settings** > **Appearance** then mark the photo with clock on it at the right side.

Comment: The original poster doesn't want to manually change the image every ten minutes... they want to be able to set it up to run automatically from a directory of images that they choose.