# How do I create a new wallpaper slideshow?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

There's a set of psychadelic pictures I'd really like to have on loop for my wallpaper to get lost in right now, but can't seem to figure out how to combine them into one stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow

Comment: Yo man. I didn't realize this was a duplicate, yo. How do I close this? Or something, man? I apologize. Totally my fault. Oh god. I almost didn't get that last sentence out. I got like lost in the word fault.