# How to get desktop background picture changed periodically?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)
>   [How do I set my wallpaper to auto-change periodically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174460/how-do-i-set-my-wallpaper-to-auto-change-periodically)

Can I set up desktop background picture to be set a random file from a given directory every given period of time?

Comment: Related: [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow) - however this question differs in requesting pictures from a directory to be shown rather than pre-specified ones