# Create live wallpaper slideshow that changes based on date rather than duration

Tags: 10.04, desktop-background

I'm trying to create a live wallpaper slideshow that will display a specific image for every day of the year. Effectively a live desktop calendar.

I've seen the question [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow) , but I want to ask something more specific: How can I specify displaying a specific image on a specific date? For instance, is there an "isdate" boolean operator I can use here? Or Is there some way I could hack the `<starttime>` section to make it display a specific image by date? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: May be you could take some idea from http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/this-neat-wallpaper-for-ubuntu-changes-with-the-time-of-day/

Comment: Hmm. That's a start. But it only pulls the date once, during install, to set the `<starttime>`. I need something that would allow me to call the date from within .xml, not from the .sh file. Is it possible to "getdate" from this .xml?

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably move/copy/symlink it into a specific directory, then set up a daily cron job to look there for the day's wallpaper and set it accordingly. However, I leave it to someone with more free time than I to help beyond that. (In response to @RichardHolloway—http://askubuntu.com/questions/21787/how-to-get-desktop-background-picture-changed-periodically/21815#comment126777_21815—linking here.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/). If the tool can create a calendar or clock on desktop maybe it can also change the background?