# How do I set my wallpaper to auto-change periodically?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)
>   [How to get desktop background picture changed periodically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21787/how-to-get-desktop-background-picture-changed-periodically)

How can I set wallpaper to change every 5 minutes or so?

The problem is that I already got used to current ones and I want to see new wallpapers. I can search and add new ones of course but it seems too manual to me.

Are there any services which provide daily fresh wallpapers? How can I set my system to automatically download and use the new ones?