# How do I install the Live Wallpaper application?

Tags: software-installation, customization, desktop-background

I found out about this software in another question, but I can't comment there as I'm new. I'm also new to Ubuntu and Linux. The app I see mentioned often is called "[Live Wallpaper](https://launchpad.net/livewallpaper)". How EXACTLY do I add it and configure the package? In as much detail as you can spare a new user, please.

Comment: Can you please give a link to the thread? Most of the time, `sudo apt-get install [program name]` will work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40423/how-can-i-set-an-animated-background           like i said, im super new to ubuntu and i cant get all the way through the 'install'

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
livewallpaper-config
```

Comment: that fyrmir part... is that supposed to be my username? just want to make sure, also the second command gets an error must be run as boot

Comment: @kyodake why installing repository as a #root? I edited your answer to make it easier to understand ;)