# Applying gif as wallpaper

Tags: 17.10, desktop-background

I want to know if there any way by which we can apply a .gif image on our desktop as wallpaper I am using Ubuntu 17:10. I tried applying the gif as wallpaper but it was not working as it is supposed to.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/40423/295286 and https://askubuntu.com/q/817875/295286  GNOME desktop and its derivatives use xml files with reference to particular images as animation, and gifs aren't supported

Comment: Thanks, but I posted this question after checking out those questions.

Comment: You can download [Komorebi by following this guide on how to install and use it](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/animated-wallpaper-background-ubuntu-18-04/). The only problem with it is that if you close the app it will close the GIF wallpaper and it would turn to the normal wallpaper you had before.