# Need a decent wallpaper changer for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-recommendation, 11.10, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

What is a good reliable wallpaper manager/switcher/changer/etc for Ubuntu 11.10?  I used to use Desktopnova in 11.04 but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I have all the required packages installed for Desktopnova.  Wally doesn't seem to work anymore either, and I don't really like wallch.  Are there any other options at this time?

Comment: Have you tried CREBS? Look at this question here - [How do I create a desktop slideshow](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

Comment: unfortunately i can't get that link to open. :(

Comment: That link definitely works, I checked it twice and have checked it just now again :)

Comment: This link? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/crebs-ultimate-wallpaper-slideshow.html   ...Because clicking that link gives me this error: Connect failed: Access denied for user 'omgsql'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: There is another question on this site itself, here's the link again - http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow

Comment: @Shawn that it probably a temporary issue.