# How to change the desktop wallpaper that's part of a slideshow?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I am currently running Ubuntu 11.10 running Gnome 3/ Gnome shell. I love the new Ubuntu desktop backgrounds, especially the one that changes periodically. However, that angular cat graphic drives me nuts. I've deleted it on other systems and it breaks the slideshow.

Is there a safe way to edit that rotation so I can get rid of the cat without disabling the slides?

Comment: I've found `variety` is a great package to handle dynamic wallpapers too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

--After installing `wallch` (from the software centre) you can safely remove the offending wallpaper.

[image]

---

[Wallch PPA Gnome3](https://launchpad.net/~wallch/+archive/wallch-ppa)

[Wallch PPA Gnome2](https://launchpad.net/~wallch/+archive/wallch-gnome2)

Linked Question:

1. [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit */usr/share/backgrounds/contest/background-1.xml* file with `gksudo gedit /usr/share/backgrounds/contest/background-1.xml` and replace the entries that read `/usr/share/backgrounds/Stalking_Ocelot_by_Sayantan_Chaudhuri.jpg` with the path to a wallpaper that's something more pleasant to you.