# Where is the list with the wallpapers (shown in the appearance window) stored?

Tags: desktop-background, appearance

When trying to add wallpapers from previous Ubuntu versions & those I found on the internet (following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116494/how-can-i-add-more-wallpapers)), I somehow messed up the list of wallpapers included in the appearance window: Most wallpapers are doubled, and only one of the wallpapers I added in the `/usr/share/backgrounds` folder got permanently added to the list shown.
[image]
Now, what I wonder: Where is the list stored of pictures shown in the appearance window? Or is there no such list? In the latter case: What factors determine which pictures in the backgrounds folder are displayed (and which aren't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You will find the wallpaper files -- backgrounds in the directory `/usr/share/backgrounds/` (but you already know that).
- The lists of these files are found in XML files in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/`.