# Wallch not auto-cycling backgrounds on log in

Tags: desktop-background

I'm extremely new to Ubuntu, and the Linux environment in general, so I could probably be doing something stupid, or not realizing how to do it, or its working and I don't realize it - so I just want to apologize for that in advance.

Going to my question, how do you make Wallch cycle through the backgrounds as a background process?  Currently, I have to have the actual GUI for it open in order for it to actually cycle through the backgrounds.  I find this highly aggravating because it entails me having to open up the program, run the background changing process, and then keep this program open.  So is there any way by which Wallch can auto-start the background changing process and keep this process going the entire time?

EDIT:
To clarify this, I was always able to make Wallch cycle through the backgrounds, but not as a background process.  I've been able to find out how to do this by checking out [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow).  If you have it set to your launcher, you can just right-click on it and then select the "Start Changing Wallpapers" button from the menu that comes up to make it run as a background process.  However, I was not able to find out how to make Wallch auto-start the cycling from the moment you log on, I always had to do the right-click and start whenever I log on again.  So is there any way that this cycling can start from the moment I log on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a timing issue with the startup application with the command line

```
wallch --constant
```

I would suggest you introduce a short delay before starting `wallch` as a background process.

Search in *Dash* for *startup application*

Then add a new startup application:

[image]

Use a startup application command line of:

```
sh -c "sleep 10 && wallch --constant &"
```