# Can I have my own collection of pictures (one fading into another) as my background?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

I've seen certain Ubuntu wallpapers which is a collection and one keeps fading into another. Is it possible to create such a set of pictures of our own to be used as the desktop wallpaper?

Comment: It is easy, for example you can use Shotwell: http://askubuntu.com/a/120965/46531. You find the pictures in /usr/share/backgrounds. (Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/134/46531)