# How to make a login screen display an auto-changing background?

Tags: login-screen

Is there a way to make the login screen show an auto-changing background, as to be able to create an animation-like screen?

I have used Ubuntu-tweak but that didn't help. Can I manually edit the configuration files to add an array of images or something?

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and this question at time of posting would be for Ubuntu 12.04 or less which means EOL. There are no answers and no comments on this question so I'm VTC'ing as `not reproducible`.  That said this question could be answered by a combining these two answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884858/how-to-cycle-through-grub-background-images-every-boot/885030#885030 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/871312/nautilus-can-set-desktop-wallpaper-how-can-it-set-login-and-lock-screen-wallpap/871313#871313 That said I prefer to post a modern question that can be accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)