# Changing backgrounds in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

I updated Ubuntu on my computer and I seen, that there is a daily changing option in background menu, but I can't set my own pictures/wallpapers as changing background. I typed "gsku nautilus", copied my wallpapers to the /usr/share/backgrounds, but I haven't seen my wallpapers at the setup menu.

Can anybody type it, how to set my own wallpapers as changing backgrounds? (I'm a beginner.)
Thank you!