# How do I set my own pictures to change on my desktop? (like every few minutes or so?)

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

Okay, so, I would like to have my background change without me having to do so. sounds so weird to say that, but, I've updated to 12.04, and I've searched the topic- but the only things I've come across is "How do I stop my desktop pictures from changing?" and "Why do they change".

I only found one post almost directly related but I had my brain melt on me in confusion. I am an ABSOLUTE beginner- and I've been trying to learn more- but I get so confused. I saw you could set it like that and I only have one- but I want it to be my pictures. (And I've had no luck looking for how to do that myself.).

So, Could someone please tell me (Step by step, the whys for the steps- I Am a baby at this, like I said.), how to have my background change every few minutes, hours- every time I log on (Just CHANGE!).... but have them be MY pictures. I'd very much appreciate the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, most (if not all) require installing a program and there are several to choose from. For the purpose of simplicity, I will just choose one program for you - wallch (Automatic Desktop Wallpaper Changer). You can install it with whatever package manager you so choose but here are the terminal commands.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open your terminal

Install wallch

```
sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Once you open the program has finished installing, open it.

In the left pane, you will notice where you can specify images or directories as well as time intervals for the background changes.