# How to make custom desktop background with multiple images?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, desktop-background

On windows XP it's possible to make desktop to display html content and thereafter add a several images on it, you can move and resize them. So the basic idea is that you place the images you like on your desktop, place them where you like, resize them as you like, then lock them, so they became part of the desktop image.

**How this can be done in ubuntu (xubuntu) ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this, firstly you can create a slideshow which will transition multiple images 1 at a time.  See [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow) on how to do it.

However, if my understanding is correct, you are asking how to create a customised background with multiple images.

To do this you need to use an **image editing software** (like GIMP) with layering capability.  In this software you can build your custom background as you like with multiple image with the ability to place, resize, rotate etc.  You can the "lock" the layers and use the image you create as your desktop background.  FYI, GIMP is available from the ubuntu software centre and is quite difficult to use for a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Builtin image viewing software Shotwell has an option.

Open "Shotwell", then import images to it or if previously showing then select your images, then go to Shotwell "file" and select "set as desktop slideshow" and choose time gap. I think it will work.

As in windows we can normally change background image using mouse right click on desktop background and "next desktop background", while many images are selected for desktop background. But in Ubuntu it will not happened.