# where are the ubuntu-desktop settings?

Tags: settings, system-settings

I just installed the Ubuntu desktop (`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) for the first time. I guess this is Unity.

I wonder where I can find the settings. There was the "System Settings" tool right in the launcher but it only has some very basic settings - I am missing basically everything. I was searching:

- how I can change my default mouse cursor
- how can I setup the background so that it fades through a predefined set (or just a directory) of pictures
- how I can change the default font and other font settings
- where can I tweak the graphics settings (this was Compiz earlier, not sure if it still is)

Etc...

Comment: Please split this up into individual questions, most of these are answered on the site already and the system only really works with one question per post, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro: Are these really separate questions? I was expecting a single answer with a single tool which just provides all standard system settings (like the ones I listed).

Comment: Yep, each one has a post on the site already. There isn't really a single tool that does all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that the "System settings" is too basic now. But, this will soon be fixed. For now, you can have Ubuntu tweak to do the tricks.

> how I can change my default mouse cursor

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

> how can I setup the background so that it fades through a predefined set (or just a directory) of pictures

There is one wallpaper setting which will rotates/changes the wallpaper after specified amount of time. Right click on desktop → *Change desktop background* and select the wallpaper which has a clock icon in it.

You can also look at this question:

- [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

> how I can change the default font and other font settings

Ubuntu tweak will help there. Install it. Open it and go to *Tweak* tab and then *Fonts* settings

> where can I tweak the graphics settings (this was Compiz earlier, not sure if it still is)

Ubuntu tweak has some options. You can also try compizconfig-settings-manager. But be warned, it is too advanced tool

```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Answer (score 2):

try installing gnome-tweak-tool via terminal and search for advanced options in dash to launch it.:
`

- sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

[image]

Also use ubuntutweak app to manage theme too.

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa && sudo apt-get update &&
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

You can easily manage themes ans cursor settings with this two.

Variety is nice app released for quantal to change wallpapers.

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa && sudo apt-get update &&
  sudo apt-get install variety

  Also try myunity programm for configuring unity in software center.
- sudo apt-get install myunity