# Enable random desktop wallpaper change with elapsed time

Tags: desktop-background

Is there a way to randomise the Ubuntu desktop wallpaper with time for each displayed wallpaper?

This will randomly select a wallpaper from the Pictures folder and display it for the specified time allocated to it in a slideshow.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/134/58950. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I have wanted to do the same thing at times.

There were a few options out there, one of the better ones that I remember is [Wallch](http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/).

You get some control over the interval and you get to add all the individual images you wish to use.

[Wallch Website](http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/)