# How do I enable the user dynamic wallpaper in the login screen of Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, 13.04, desktop-background

Ubuntu 12.04 Unity greeter had introduced the *selected user dynamic wallpaper* which allowed, when selecting a user from the available users list in the login screen, the wallpaper to change to reflect the selected user's desktop wallpaper.

Apparently that feature has been disabled by default since Ubuntu 12.10.

How do I enable that feature in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Maybe investigating the file `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` ([from @Hernantz's answer to the same question](http://askubuntu.com/a/64003/58950))?

Comment: I am pretty sure it should be enabled by default, and not disabled... some sort of bug perhaps?

Comment: @Gui it was enabled by default on 12.04, it was disabled since 12.10. I have experienced that both on my desktop and laptop.

Comment: @Krige I don't know, but I can tell you that I am running 12.10 and it works fine for me...

Comment: @carnendil my unity-greeter.cong contains only three lines. I don't think it is used anymore as I read it was replaced with gsettings.

Comment: @Gui you were right, it actually works. I have found out it didn't won't work because I had selected the option to change the wallpaper throughout the day. I opened a bug on launchpad about it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1173691 and added an answer to state my findings.

Comment: I think this is the best way for dynamic wallpaper.
No extra software needed
http://askubuntu.com/a/120965/357834

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
```

**Note**: the selected user dynamic wallpaper works only if you have a fixed wallpaper. It won't work if you have selected the option to *change throughout the day*.