# Change wallpaper automatically in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: desktop-background

well I'm new on ubuntu, I installed the 13.10 version because I heard it's faster and smoothly than 12.04. So, my problem is that I don't know how to change wallpapers in an automatic way (slideshow), but with my OWN pictures, I don't want pictures from flicker, etc. I want to have wallpapers of pictures that I have already downloaded. I searched some programs and I found Slidewall but I can't download it in ubuntu 13.10. Could anybody lend me some help? (sorry if there's a English confusion, I'm not too good at it)

Comment: `wallch` found in ubuntu 13.10,you can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crebs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install crebs
```

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25549/how-to-create-a-wallpaper-slideshow-in-ubuntu/

Comment: This is what appears on the terminal... Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package crebs

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands to install `wallch`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Then follow the `wallch` post in [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

Comment: That is constantly crashing. I really don't understand what others find in that software...