# how do i create a slideshow in GIMP for a wallpaper

Tags: slideshow

how do i create a slideshow in GIMP image editor using jpeg images saved in a folder and use it as wallpaper in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version? The slideshow has to be timed so that the wallpaper keeps changing at fixed time interval, and background music is also present..

Comment: You do not need GIMP for making a slideshow for wallpapers in Ubuntu. You need images and create an XML. No GIMP needed. Wallpapers can not use audio.

Comment: and if you want you can use `wallch` You just add the images and set a timer for it to create a wallpaper changer for you.

Comment: @Rinzwind Also He/She asked in different question about `wallch` here http://askubuntu.com/questions/525151/wallch-doesnt-support-jpeg-pictures

Comment: @KasiyA yeah I deleted my answer on that one :D  Here is an example how to MANUALLY create a slideshow: http://askubuntu.com/a/10943/15811

Comment: slideshow + background music for a wallpaper? i think you missed what a wallpaper is.... if you want a slideshow with audio you can use a lot of different software, "photofilmstrip" for example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need Gimp to do this thing. There are several methods to set multiple images as your desktop wallpaper and change periodically. Here I am explaining a method which does not require installation of any new packages.

First Goto Programs and open Shotwell. It comes pre-installed with Ubuntu. Now You can see the images in your Library. You can import as much as images you want. After doing this select the images you want to set as you wallpaper.

And then goto `File`->`Set as Desktop Slideshow`

Adjust your time delay.
Done!!