# Shotwell Desktop Slideshow Transitions

Tags: shotwell, slideshow

Is there a way to add some transition to shotwell's desktop slideshow? Preferably just a smooth fade between the pictures. They just "cut in" one after the other.

Comment: I don't think you can add transitions to shotwell, I could be wrong, so not duping this but check here for some alternatives to shotwell http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow

Answer (score 0):

In Shotwell 0.15.1:  Start a slideshow using **View -> slideshow**.

During the slideshow at the bottom of each photo there is a little tab
showing stuff:  leftarrow, stop, rightarrow, settings, back to thumbnails.

Click on settings and have a field day.