# How to create image carousel in lockscreen?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, lock-screen

Is there any way to create an image carousel in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or higher? Similar to the Windows 10 feature where in everyday, different photo is being displayed.

Comment: Perhaps some information here: http://askubuntu.com/q/134/57576 ?

Comment: So if I understand correctly,  your main requirement is that depending on the day of the week , you have different lock-screen background, is that correct ? I may need to figure out how to do it with lock-screen, but  off the top of my head I can come up with a few ideas for login screen ( the one after boot ).

Comment: @Serg Yes, exactly. That's what I want. It would be very helpful if you could suggest anything which is capable of doing the same.

Comment: well, I could write a script that does that. I have one for changing background of login screen already. With lock screen ( the one opened via Ctrl + Alt + L ) usually displays only user desktop wallpaper, so It's a bit more challenging, because you need to alter image before and restore image after locking.

Answer (score 0):

Go for variety, its the best out there.

Variety is packed with great features, yet slim and easy to use.

It can use local images or automatically download wallpapers from lots of online sources, allows you to rotate them on a regular interval, and provides easy ways to separate the great images from the junk.

Variety can also display wise and funny quotations or a nice digital clock on the desktop.

To install type in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

To launch variety type in terminal:

```
variety
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It'll be applicable in lockscreens too, right?