# Automatic Wallpaper changer option

Tags: desktop-background

How to setup or activate Automatic wallpaper changer option in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 Lts Verstions.{as an option in windows 7 OS}

Comment: This question has been answered many times here.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow

Comment: What was [tag: command-line] doing in this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

Answer (score 3):

Install Wallch or Variety.

1. Installing Variety in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install variety
   link: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2016/05/install-variety-ubuntu-16-04/
2. Installing Wallch in
   **(i)Ubuntu 16.04**
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wallch
   link: http://sourcedigit.com/19635-install-wallch-wallpaper-changer-on-ubuntu-16-04/
   **(ii)Ubuntu 14.04**
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-4.0
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wallch
   link: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2695881/install-wallch-4-5-wallpaper-changer-in-ubuntu-14-04.html