# How can I add *my own* desktop picture to 19.04?

Tags: desktop-environments, desktop-background

When I go to change background I can select system pictures.

[image]

How do I add to those pictures, e.g. pick from my computer?
I see that pictures are in `/usr/share/backgrounds`
But I don't have privs to paste an image in their (i am an admin btw)

Comment: In Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gs-change-wallpaper.html.en

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/10943/739431

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add your own pictures to the dialog that you are revealing in the screen print, add the files to the folder `.local/share/backgrounds` in your home folder. `.local` can by default not be seen, because all files and folders where the name starts with a `.` are hidden folders. Set the option to reveal hidden files in your file manager (usually, you can also set that with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>). Create the `backgrounds` folder if it does not exist. Background images in the user's `.local/share/backgrounds` folder will be available to the current user only.

If you want the pictures to be available for all users of the system, then indeed copy them to `/usr/share/backgrounds`. Of course, because this is a system folder, you need to have root privileges in order to be able to copy files into that directory.

Answer (score 1):

This has caught me more than once.

Go to the pictures you want in the file explorer and right click and choose

'Set As Wallpaper'

[image]